# Windows form progress bar not working?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a button .It will open a file and process a file .I want to show the progress bar while processing the file .

when i am doing .its working

```
public MainframeDataExchangeTool()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _ProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
    _ProgressBar.Visible = false;
    _Random = new Random();
    InitializeBackgroundWorker();
}

private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
{
    _BackgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    _BackgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

    _BackgroundWorker.DoWork += (sender, e) => ((MethodInvoker)e.Argument).Invoke();
    _BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        _ProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
        _ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    };
    _BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (_ProgressBar.Style == ProgressBarStyle.Marquee)
        {
            _ProgressBar.Visible = false;
        }
    };
}
```

In my button click i am doing

```
private void btnOpenScriptFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        loadScriptFlDlg.Filter = Constants.SCRIPT_FILE_FILTER;
        loadScriptFlDlg.FilterIndex = 3;
        loadScriptFlDlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
        loadScriptFlDlg.FileName = string.Empty;
        DialogResult objDialogResult = loadScriptFlDlg.ShowDialog();

        if (objDialogResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {
            _BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                _ProgressBar.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => _ProgressBar.Visible = true));
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(10);
                    _BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i);
                }
            }));
            EnableDisableControls("OpenScript");
            string strScriptError = LoadScriptFromFile(loadScriptFlDlg.FileName);///loading will taking time but progress bar not showing
```

Basically progress bar is showing at the end of data load but not while loading the data

Comment: I tend to use the progress bar with backgroundworker in c#. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes i have tried it but my question is will it work in the same form ..

Comment: Don't understand your question - here is a link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo

Comment: @DanielCasserly Thanks ...i have updated my question...can you help me on the same

Comment: @defaultlocale if you're going to bump old questions to remove tags, please fix the other issues (capitalization etc) as well.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I'm sorry for disturbing you. I'll try to make my edits (attempt to clean up [winforms](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266755/possible-tag-synonyms-forms-and-html-form)) more significant. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot see the progress as UI thread cannot update UI because it is busy loading your file. You must call `LoadScriptFromFile` from the background worker and keep UI thread free to process events and update UI.

Comment: ...I get your point very much ...can you please help me with a sample coding ......

Comment: Even if i tried that i am getting cross thread error ..Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats your code in `LoadScriptFromFile` ? Is it changing any control in addition to loading the file? You may need to re-factor it.

Comment: Yes ..its enable/disable controls...where i am getting error,,

Comment: You should call `LoadScriptFromFile` from background worker and as you read the file, call `_BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress()`. If you want to change controls from inside of `LoadScriptFromFile`, then you should use `yourControl.Invoke` and enable/disable that control from delegate passed to `Invoke`.

Comment: See code sample here: http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/c-download-file-progress-bar They are downloading a file with progress bar. You just have to write similar code for reading the file. I assume thats what you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

Surprised the compiler didn't throw a hissy fit...because you need an extra }.

You open 4 levels of nesting, but only close 3.

I have modified your code as shown below:

```
private void btnOpenScriptFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      if (objDialogResult.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
      {
         _ProgressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
         _ProgressBar.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => _ProgressBar.Visible = true));
         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         {
         Thread.Sleep(10);
         _ProgressBar.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => _ProgressBar.Value = i));
         //Process my file here
         }
      }
   }
   Catch
   {
   }
}
```

I would always suggest reducing the number of empty lines, for readability.
I also find that the 'allman' style bracketing is easiest to debug.

But as always, each to his own.

EDIT:

After OP editted code:

Try adding:

```
application.doevents()
```

after your:

```
_BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i);
```

Why? The code will stay in the for loop until completes. By doing 'doevents' you are telling it to update externally, before the next loop.

Without the 'doevents' i guess you would see 0 and 100 only.

Comment: ..My bad i just post a prtt of my code ...I have updated it ...can you please help

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my project with 2 methode (exemple):

1* Invoke(new Action(() => _ProgressBar.Visible = true));

2* or use `Application.DoEvents()` after your `_BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i);`

Answer (score 0):

Simply do something like this with a BackgroundWorker (bgw).

```
    private void MyMethod()
    {
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync(); //this calls the DoWork event
    }

    private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Expensive task
        //Calculate how far you through your task (ie has read X of Y bytes of file)
        bgw.ReportProgress(myInteger);
    }

    private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        myProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

Make sure you set the BackgroundWorker's "WorkerReportsProgress" property to True!