# BackgroundWorker, how Could i show real progress? C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I've created application that encrypt/decrypt file using AES, but when I need to do something with big files, i need to wait few seconds, and as a consequence of this my UI aren't respond. I know how to use BackgroundWorker to show progress in progressBar or something else, but idk how to show REAL! progress of for example decrypting the file.

Long story short, I want to display in progressBar actuall progress of file decryption, so user will know how much he need wait to end.

I use this code to decrypt specific file with specific AES KEY (password),
I'm doing it in another class but in the same thread that UI is working.

```
public void FileDecrypt(string inputFile, string password) {

            byte[] passwordBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
            byte[] salt = new byte[32];

            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);
            fsCrypt.Read(salt, 0, salt.Length);

            RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();
            AES.KeySize = 256;
            AES.BlockSize = 128;
            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, salt, 50000);
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
            AES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;

            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            string getFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(inputFile), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(inputFile));

            string fileDirectoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(getFilePath);

            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(getFilePath);

            fileName += "_decrypted";

            string fileExtenstion = Path.GetExtension(getFilePath);

            string finalFileNameFinal = fileDirectoryPath + "\\" + fileName + fileExtenstion;

            FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(finalFileNameFinal, FileMode.Create);


            int read;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576];

            try {
                while ((read = cs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    fsOut.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
            } catch (CryptographicException ex_CryptographicException) {
                Console.WriteLine("CryptographicException error: " + ex_CryptographicException.Message);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }

            try {
                cs.Close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("Error by closing CryptoStream: " + ex.Message);
            } finally {
                fsOut.Close();
                fsCrypt.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does the encrypt/decrypt function inform you about the ongoing progress or is it a blocking call that just returns when the full file is done? If it just returns, what parameters does it consume? If it is a stream you could write a proxy stream to be informed how much bytes of the file have been read or written.

Comment: If you block the UI thread, then you don't use the `BackgroundWorker` correctly. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19410765/5114784) answer help?

Comment: `Real Progress` is subjective, it depends entirely on what you are using as a measurement, for example, if you're using the count of files in a directory / folder that are being decrypted, you can report the progress of each individual file which will give some indication of how many tasks are left.

But in terms of an estimation of time, they'll never be 100% `real` as each file can have varying file sizes and take different times to perform the action against them.

The reason your UI isn't responding is because you're doing work in your UI thread instead of in a background process.

Comment: @Oliver i will just edit my post to show you some code.

Comment: Following on from my previous comment, to update your UI thread, I would suggest making a new method that has the following if statement condition inside of it: 

`private void UpdateProgressOnUi(int value) { if (this.InvokeRequired) { this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.UpdateProgress(value))); return; } this.UpdateProgress(value); }`

Comment: The CryptoStream accepts a Stream for input and can write a buffer you specify. So you can define the progress in the encryption by dividing the file size by 100, count the size of the buffer written per iteration and report progress each time you reach 1/100 of the overall size. -- Note that the CryptoStream provides async methods, you don't need a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: If, for any reason, you prefer / need to run Tasks instead, you can use an [IProgress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) delegate to updated the UI (it's a simple method declared in the Thread that requires the updates, it can also be in-lined).

Comment: I see neither the mentioned progress bar update nor `BackgroundWorker` in the code. And the `Application.DoEvents` line gives me the hint that you use the UI thread for the potentially long-lasting operation.

Comment: One possibility: Your method gets a third parameter `Action<double> progress` and instead of calling `Application.DoEvents()` you call something like `progress((double)bytesRead / fileLength * 100)` and from the outside you put your method into a `BackgroundWorker` and use its report progress method as action method for your method.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> but idk how to show REAL! progress of for example decrypting the file.

The answer depends on what you define as "REAL!" progress. Is that the number of seconds since you started decrypting your file, or is it the number of seconds that you expect will take to finish. Or maybe a percentage: seconds passed divided by total expected duration?

And "for example". Apparently you want this also for other processes that take some time.

Alas, there is no common answer for all these possibilities. Even for decrypting the file there is no method to measure the time needed to decrypt the rest of your file. When decrypting, there is no guarantee that decrypting the first 1000 bytes will take the same amount of time as decrypting the last 1000 bytes.

However, if you define the following as "REAL! progress", you could try something:

> **Definition:** when decrypting a stream, the REAL! progress of the decryption process is defined as the number of bytes that are decrypted relative to the total length of the stream to decrypt.

In other words: if your input stream is 1000k, and you already decrypted 250k, then your REAL! progress is 250k/1000k = 0.25, or 25%.

Alas, this is not a value that describes how much time will be needed to decrypt the rest of the file, but at least it gives the operator an indication.

By the way: consider to use `using` more often, so you don't have to `Close` / `Dispose` your Streams manually.

```
using (var inputStream = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open))
{
    long totalInputLength = inputStream.Length;

    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(inputStream,
           AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
        using (var outputStream = new FileStream(finalFileNameFinal, FileMode.Create))
        {
            long totalNumberOfBytesRead = 0;
            var numberOfBytesRead = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            while (numberOfBytesRead > 0)
            {
                totalNumberOfBytesRead += numberOfBytesRead;
                double realProgress = (double) totalNumberOfBytesRead /
                                      (double) totalInputLength;
                ReportProgress(realProgress);
                outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (...) {...}
```

Note: the using statements will take care the the streams are Flushed / Closed / Disposed, even after exceptions.